# Как в laravel 5 написать проверку страны, чтоб перенаправить по умолчанию на страницу на соответствующем языке?

Tags: php, css, laravel

Есть проект, написанный на laravel 5 на двух страницах (одна страница на русском, другая на английском). Подскажите, как сделать так, чтоб заходя на этот проект из стран СНГ он переходил на русскую страницу, а из остальных стран - открывалась английская страница. Где и что нужно прописать?
П.С. я так понимаю, что нужна какая-то проверка,но вот какая и куда ее прописать....подскажите подалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать Geo IP, для Laravel есть компонент, называется [Laravel Geoip](http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/)

Устанавливаете как указано в документации и потом с помощью функции geoip() узнаете в какой стране пользователь, в ответ получите примерно такой ответ:

```
\Torann\GeoIP\Location {

    #attributes:array [
        'ip'           => '232.223.11.11',
        'iso_code'     => 'US',
        'country'      => 'United States',
        'city'         => 'New Haven',
        'state'        => 'CT',
        'state_name'   => 'Connecticut',
        'postal_code'  => '06510',
        'lat'          => 41.28,
        'lon'          => -72.88,
        'timezone'     => 'America/New_York',
        'continent'    => 'NA',
        'currency'     => 'USD',
        'default'      => false,
    ]
}
```

И исходя из этих данных уже делаете проверку какую страницу показать.

Comment: спасибо огромное!